# How display the first element of a list ? Smarty, Prestashop module

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

I'm trying to change a view in a Prestashop Module. I would like to display just the first one case of a list.

Here, is the original list:

```
 {if count($tax_details)>0 && $use_taxes}
        <br />
        <br />
        <table cellpadding="3">
            <thead>
                <tr style="color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #4D4D4D; font-weight:bold; padding:2px;">
                    <th style="width: 40%;">{l s='TAX DETAILS' mod='opartdevis'}</th>
                    <th style="width: 20%;">{l s='Tax rate' mod='opartdevis'}</th>
                    <th style="width: 20%;">{l s='Total without tax' mod='opartdevis'}</th>
                    <th style="width: 20%;text-align: right;">{l s='Total tax' mod='opartdevis'}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            {foreach $tax_details as $tax}
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 40%;">{$tax.prefix|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</td>
                    <td style="width: 20%;">{$tax.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</td>
                    <td style="width: 20%;">{Tools::displayPrice($tax.total_ht)}</td>
                    <td style="width: 20%;text-align: right;">{Tools::displayPrice($tax.total_tax)}</td>
                </tr>
            {/foreach}
        </table>
    {/if}
```

It display this :
[image]

And I would like to display just this number in yellow on another place.
[image]

This is my code (it situated on the same page than the original list):

```
 {if count($tax_details)>0}
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="7" style="text-align:right;">
                            Total éco taxes : 
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="1" style="text-align:right;">
                            <span id="total_price_remiseincl">
                                {Tools::displayPrice($tax_details[0].total_tax)}
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {/if}
```

I have this error:
[image]

I tried many ways to write it, but I don't find how to do.

Could you help me pls ? I'm new with Smarty.

Thanks in advance
Malaury

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a loop again

```
{assign 't' '0'}
{foreach $tax_details as $tax}
    {if $t === '0'}
      {Tools::displayPrice($tax.total_tax)}
      {assign 't' '1'}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the 'first' properly like below. ([docs](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl))

In your foreach, use,

```
{if $smarty.foreach.tax_details.first}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td style="width: 20%;text-align: right;">
            {Tools::displayPrice($tax.total_tax)}
        </td>
    </tr>
{/if}
```